# Best Approaches to summarize or aggregate multiple rows to single row for Machine learning model creation

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, aggregate, data-analysis

Creating a ML model for predictive maintenance .

table A contains log information with start time , end time and event status.
**table A**

| Id | startTime | endTime | event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 7/1/2021 1:05:04 | 7/1/2021 1:06:04 | OS |

Table B contains multiple records of what are the temperature (for each seconds) present for the event  in table A .

**Table B**

| Id | startTime | endTime | time(seconds) | temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 7/1/2021 1:05:04 | 7/1/2021 1:06:04 | 1 | 0.23 |
| 100 | 7/1/2021 1:05:04 | 7/1/2021 1:06:04 | 2 | 0.32 |
| 100 | 7/1/2021 1:05:04 | 7/1/2021 1:06:04 | 55 | 0.41 |
| 100 | 7/1/2021 1:05:04 | 7/1/2021 1:06:04 | 56 | 0.36 |
| 100 | 7/1/2021 1:05:04 | 7/1/2021 1:06:04 | 57 | 0.32 |
| 100 | 7/1/2021 1:05:04 | 7/1/2021 1:06:04 | 58 | 0.41 |
| 100 | 7/1/2021 1:05:04 | 7/1/2021 1:06:04 | 59 | 0.35 |

What is the best way to aggregate table B, so that i can merge with table A for creating ML models.

Used Mean () and standard deviation for the aggregation, but feel like there is chances of losing actual data information.

Is there any great way to handle this kind of data or any other statistical method will be useful in this case as the temperature in each second is more critical  when dealing with error analysis

Answer (score 0):

If mean and standard deviation is not working, you could try to see how well Table A and Table B correlates. Try to find matches between the two tables. Fill missing values with mean or remove them entirely if the missing values are a lot.

Imputing missing values could be done by

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].fillna(df['column_namae'].mean()[0])
```

Also, check the correlation between the features to get which features correlate with the target.

```
df.corr()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Mean and std is working and able to aggregate the values into a single row information. But i would like to understand what is the best approach's to handle this kind of information ?